# PHP 5.4: convert between date formats

Tags: php, date

I have dates in the following format:

```
2016-10-12
|    |  |
YEAR M  D
```

and I need:

```
12.10.16
|  |  |
D  M  YEAR
```

I have managed to parse date in source format:

```
$date = date_parse_from_format('YYYY-mm-dd', $dateYYYYMMDD);
```

But I am having trouble converting it to a new format. Could  you please help.

Comment: `$dateDDMMYY = date('d.m.y', strtotime($dateYYYYMMDD));`

Answer (score 0):

Most flexible is to use the `Datetime` class:

```
<?php
$date = new Datetime('2016-10-12');
var_dump($date->format('d.m.y'));
```

The output obviously is:

```
string(8) "12.10.16"
```